# Read File properties

Tags: c#

I am trying to read the file properties, For example If i change the file extension of test.txt file into test_txt.vsf, the type of file still .txt in file properties. I want to read this file extension from properties.

I am usinf below code which displays the file name extension as .vsf. But actually it's extension is .txt.

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\saravana_rajkumar\Desktop\Test_txt.vsf");
Console.WriteLine(info.Extension);
```

Please guide...

Comment: How are you changing the extension of the file? `FileInfo` doesn't have a link to the file on disk so if you modify it outside of the `FileInfo` object, it doesn't know about that. `Refresh` can update the properties, but changing the name of the file "unhooks" it from the `FileInfo` object.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the data actually in a file is not stored anywhere by Windows. It is up to applications to determine if they can handle a file they are given.

For example, if you rename an EXE to ".txt" you can try to open it with Notepad, and it will try to open it as a text file.

When you say this:

> If i change the file extension of test.txt file into test_txt.vsf, the type of file still .txt in file properties.

You are wrong. The type of the file is *not* still ".txt" in file properties. The file properties for *file type* in Windows Explorer works solely off the file suffix.

Comment: Try following below steps.

Comment: @saravanakumarr Which steps?

Comment: Try following below steps. 1) Create test.txt file. 2)Rename it as test_txt.vsf. 3)Right Click that file & see Type of file. It is (.txt).. I want to read that extension. 4)Also see Details tab, where see the name. it is showing as test_txt.vsf.txt. So the actual file extension is .txt..

Comment: @saravanakumarr Step (3) for me says the type of file is VSF, as I expected. You are clearly failing to rename the file.

Comment: @saravanakumarr (1) Right-click desktop, select New|Text Document". (2) Right-click file from step 1 and select "Rename". Delete the ".txt" from the end and replace it with ".vsf". Press "return" and accept the "are you sure?" question. (3) Right-click the file, look at properties and see that the "type of file" now says ".vsf". This is basic stuff, and it's how it has worked since Windows 95.

Comment: Actually i hided file extension, This is where confusion happened...I got things now..

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried to use `Path.ChangeExtension` method ?

Check out [Path.ChangeExtension documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx) in MSDN

Example:

```
string newFileName = Path.ChangeExtension("test_txt.txt", ".vsf");
```

Comment: But this is for changing the file extension right, Not for reading the actual life extension..